# Запуск exe файла не знаю полного пути java

Tags: java, path

Я пытаюсь найти путь к исполняемой папке и запускать exe файл, но вот беда, когда я вывожу по какому пути он у меня пытается запустить exe, выходит это - `\home\container\server.exe`.
Подскажите что сделать.

Comment: Опишите подробнее суть вопроса, где откуда и как. Скорее всего он пытается запустить исполняемый файл в той же деректории, где и файл `Java`.

Comment: этот файл (jar) находится на сервере. При его запуске, он пытается найти свой же путь `Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` и потом по этому пути запустить exe. Вот только путь этот выходит, как я уже писал, `\home\container\server.exe`. По сути jar и exe файлы находятся в одной и той же дерриктории

Comment: А какой должен быть? И добавьте эти уточнения в сам вопрос, поменьше воды и побольше сути, Это поможет в более быстром ответе.

Comment: в этом и состоит вопрос, чтоб путь узнать